# RadGrid grouping issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

HTML :

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="AssignGrid" runat="server" AllowMultiRowSelection="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    SkinID="RadGridSkin" OnNeedDataSource="AssignGrid_NeedDataSource">
                    <ClientSettings>
                        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                    </ClientSettings>
                    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="CATEGORY_ID" GroupsDefaultExpanded="false">
                        <GroupByExpressions>
                            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                                <GroupByFields>
                                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="CATEGORY_ID" />
                                </GroupByFields>
                                <SelectFields>
                                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME" />
                                </SelectFields>
                            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                        </GroupByExpressions>
                        <GroupHeaderTemplate>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkCategory" class="group_check" runat="server" />
                            <span style="padding-left: 10px;">Category:
                                <%# Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME")%></span>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="Header_cat_id" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CATEGORY_ID") %>' />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="Header_cat_name" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME") %>' />
                       </GroupHeaderTemplate>
                        <Columns>
                            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="40px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="CheckRow" class="item_check" runat="server" onclick="SelectCategoryRow(this);" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                          <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PARTNER_CATEGORY_NAME" Display="false" UniqueName="PartnerCatName">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                             <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SUB_CATEGORY_ID" Display="false">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="CATEGORY_ID" Display="false">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PARTNER_SUB_CATEGORY_NAME" HeaderText="Sub-Category Name" UniqueName="PartnerSubCatName">
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </MasterTableView>
                </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Server side :

```
AssignGrid_Confirm.DataSource = AssignGrid_dt;
AssignGrid_Confirm.DataBind();
```

[image]

Result:

[image]

an empty item is being inserted ... how can i remove those empty items ???  my final grid should look like this : [image]

Comment: Remove the DataBind() call from inside the NeedDataSource handler, you only need to set the DataSource property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two empty rows correspond to the rows that do not have a sub_category_id.  You need to either remove them from your datasource before binding or you can probably set up filtering on the grid control to hide them as well.

[Telerik's demo page on filtering](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/functionality/filtering/basic-filtering/defaultcs.aspx).  I'm not sure whether you can set a filter and then not allow the user to change it - really you'll be better off removing them from your datasource to start with I would think.